# Jenkins - use slave machine for regressions test only

Tags: c#, build, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins build machine that outputs an MSI.

I need to install it on a remote machine and run there couple of tests (assume I have Regression Tests solution that is executable).

I thought maybe to have a regression machine, install there Jenkins as slave, create regression job with all the right paths that invokes the resression solution.

Is it feasible? Will the slave report to the master on asserts that were failing?

Comment: Is this tagged C# because you're running C# tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration you specify is valid, and should work,
but please note that your regression-test tool should return a *non-zero* result in case of a failure.

If this is not trivial for the test-mechanism you plan to have,
you can use one of those Plugins to scan the logs of the tests
(either on-screen or in log-files) and trap any errors
to mark that run as 'FAILED' or 'UNSTABLE':

- **[Text-finder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin)** - Simpler to configure, but has less options
- **[Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin)** - Requires a config-file, but gives more control
   (can define different rules for 'FAILED' and 'UNSTABLE' for the same Job)